# Dell laptop, Bluetooth stop working after firware upgrade

Tags: bluetooth

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on my Dell Inspirion laptop. After the last firmware upgrade (Dec, 2d, 23) the blutooth stop working. I can't see a bluetooth ddevice even in the bios info page and connecting a blutooth dongle not working wither.

Anything I can do? Is there a way to roll back the firmware?

Thanks